# View doesn't match ObservedObject

Tags: asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am using an ObservedObject with a singleton which is populated via an API call to present part of my view. However, when I update my singleton, the view isn't updated accordingly. Here is my view code:

```
struct Friends: View {
    @State private var friends: [FirestoreUser] = []
    @State private var loading = false
    @ObservedObject private var currentUser = CurrentUser.shared // singleton

 // Bunch of UI code ...

GeometryReader { subGeo in
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(friends, id: \.id) {
                                        
                 UserItem(user: $0)
                     .background(Color.white)
                                        
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color.white)
        }
        .listRowBackground(Color.white)
        Spacer()

// Some brackets and then ...
        .onReceive(self.currentUser.$user, perform: { _ in
            getFriends()
        })
```

Here's the getFriends() function:

```
func getFriends() {
        print("in get friends func")
        if let friendUIDs = currentUser.user?.firestoreFriendUIDs {
            print("getting friends for friends page")
            if friendUIDs.count > 0 {
                self.loading = true
                FirestoreService.fetchUsers(uids: friendUIDs) { (friends) in
                    self.friends = friends!
                    self.loading = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my CurrentUser class:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class CurrentUser: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var user: FirestoreUser?
    public static var shared = CurrentUser()
    
    func setUser(user: FirestoreUser) {
        self.user = user
    }
    
}
```

And here is where I'm initially setting the singleton:

```
func listen() {
        
        handle = auth.addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
        
            if let authUser = user {
                print("user in addStateDidChangeListener is not nil")
                self.loggedInFIRAuthUser = user
                FirestoreService.fetchUser(uid: authUser.uid) { (user) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        if let user = user {
                            CurrentUser.shared.setUser(user: user)
                            print("set CurrentUser singleton")
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("nil authUser")
            }
        })
    }
```

This is part of the initial view for the app. What's happening based on print messages is that the program fetches user data from Firestore when it starts up, confirms the user has friends, but onReceived is called just before the singleton is set rather than after. I even tried adding a delay, and the singleton is actually waiting for the .OnReceived code to run. The order of the printed lines is:

in get friends func

user in addStateDidChangeListener is not nil

friendUIDs.count: 1

in get friends func

set CurrentUser singleton

Any help is greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for days.

Comment: Current user is a ObservedObject... so is CurrentUser.shared class an @ObservableObject? And are the variables within the class @Published?

Comment: @nicksarno edited to add my CurrentUser class, I believe that's all I need